# Draw the arc of a circle in R

Tags: r

Is there a bug in the grid.curve function? For the life of me I can't get it to draw an arc of a circle. Is there a fix for this?

```
library(grid)

plot.new()
#main viewport
vp=viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=1, height=1)
pushViewport(vp)

#Circle
grid.circle(x=0.5, y=0.5, r=0.4,default.units="npc")

#Coordinates for gene
glength=100000
start=0
startrad=(start/glength)*2*pi
end=20000
endrad=(end/glength)*2*pi
length=end-start

xco1=0.5+0.4*cos(startrad)
yco1=0.5+0.4*sin(startrad)
xco2=0.5+0.4*cos(endrad)
yco2=0.5+0.4*sin(endrad)


grid.curve(xco1,yco1,xco2,yco2,curvature=arcCurvature((length/glength)*360),ncp=10,gp=gpar(col="blue",lwd=10,lineend=2))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Using your posted code I get it to draw a circle and an arc. Granted, the arc drawn isn't of the circle drawn but that has to do with the parameters given to `grid.curve`, especially the `curvature` parameter.
[Circle and Arc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qbp8sezpf2p4hf6/arcofcircle.jpeg)

Comment: The blue arc, is not exactly an arc. Changing the start and end parameters creates things that are much less arc-like too. Setting the curvature parameter with the arcCurvature function should create a perfect arc which overlies the circle exactly.

Comment: I think you need `square=FALSE` in your final `grid.curve` call to get a true arc and I'd double-check to ensure your start/end points are correct.

Comment: Hah!  Define "true arc" :-) . I bet @hrbrmstr is on the right track, if you want your arcs to be parts of circles.

Comment: @user3246796 Yes I see that there is some part of the arc that was straight. However, that is not an error. It is a result of how the parameters are defined or missing paramaters as both **hrbrmstr** and **Carl** suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. The answer was to include the parameter square=F.